# pass data to jquery validate plugin from remote source

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How do I configure jQuery Validate plugin using rules/messages from a remote source?  Is this correct? Thanks

```
$.getJSON( "index.php", {task:"getMyJSONforThisPage"}, function(json) {
    var signupForm=$("#get-started-form").validate(json);        
});
```

Comment: Are you having a specific problem?  So what happens when you try that?  Did you verify that your variable `json` is constructed correctly?  Where is the relevant HTML?  Answer:  it's only correct if `json` contains what it's supposed to contain.

Comment: What's the purpose of doing it like this?  Typically, when you want to use the same JavaScript on multiple pages, you simply include the relevant JavaScript file for that page.

Comment: @Sparky  The rules and messages are server generated (I define initial rules which first create jQuery Validator rules/messages and then are later used for server validation).  I could create dynamically generated JS, but would rather return JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the remote property. This example assumes the field to remotely validate is called 'captcha' and the form has an id of 'my_form'

```
var form = $('#my_form').validate(
   {
    rules: {
      captcha: {
        required: true,
        remote: {
          url: '/php/check_captcha/',
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json'
          }        
      }
    }
  });
```

The URL should be a relative to the domain where the JavaScript code is to avoid any CORS issues.

The server side should send back true or false. e.g. PHP

```
function check_captcha() {
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) { // example server side function
      echo json_encode("true");
    } else {
      echo json_encode("false");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Forgot to include link to docs [link](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/)

Comment: I think you misunderstood.  The OP is trying to load the rules & messages from the server, not doing remote validation.